# What is android.net.ZeroBalanceHelper in Android studio and why it cause errors?

Tags: android

My app is working perfectly, but there are some strange errors in stacktrace. What is android.net.ZeroBalanceHelper? I didn't even added such library in gradle, google gives no answer what it could be. These errors do not affect the functionality

Full error log:

```
07-03 20:15:54.431 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.net.ZeroBalanceHelper
07-03 20:15:54.432 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
07-03 20:15:54.432 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
07-03 20:15:54.432 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285)
07-03 20:15:54.432 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.ZeroBalanceHelperClass.getFeatureFlagValue(ZeroBalanceHelperClass.java:39)
07-03 20:15:54.432 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.followUpRequest(HttpEngine.java:1090)
07-03 20:15:54.432 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:393)
07-03 20:15:54.432 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:501)
07-03 20:15:54.432 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:567)
07-03 20:15:54.432 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:540)
07-03 20:15:54.432 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:227)
07-03 20:15:54.432 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:216)
07-03 20:15:54.432 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at ru.pacodelavega.techno_test.MainActivity$FindImagesTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:110)
07-03 20:15:54.432 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at ru.pacodelavega.techno_test.MainActivity$FindImagesTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:95)
07-03 20:15:54.433 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
07-03 20:15:54.433 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-03 20:15:54.435 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
07-03 20:15:54.436 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
07-03 20:15:54.436 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
07-03 20:15:54.436 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-03 20:15:54.436 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.net.ZeroBalanceHelper
07-03 20:15:54.436 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
07-03 20:15:54.436 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
07-03 20:15:54.436 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
07-03 20:15:54.436 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
07-03 20:15:54.437 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:    ... 19 more
07-03 20:15:54.437 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
07-03 20:15:55.354 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.net.ZeroBalanceHelper
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285)
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.ZeroBalanceHelperClass.getFeatureFlagValue(ZeroBalanceHelperClass.java:39)
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.followUpRequest(HttpEngine.java:1090)
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:393)
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:150)
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:192)
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.net.URLConnection.getContentType(URLConnection.java:325)
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:193)
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getContent(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:133)
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContent(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.net.URL.getContent(URL.java:455)
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at ru.pacodelavega.techno_test.MainActivity$FindImagesTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:117)
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at ru.pacodelavega.techno_test.MainActivity$FindImagesTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:95)
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
07-03 20:15:55.355 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-03 20:15:55.356 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.net.ZeroBalanceHelper
07-03 20:15:55.356 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
07-03 20:15:55.356 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
07-03 20:15:55.356 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
07-03 20:15:55.356 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
07-03 20:15:55.356 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err:    ... 21 more
07-03 20:15:55.356 23575-24040/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
07-03 20:16:04.795 23575-23575/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = ru.pacodelavega.techno_test
07-03 20:16:04.795 23575-23575/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test V/Monotype:     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
07-03 20:16:04.815 23575-23575/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@3037676
07-03 20:16:04.815 23575-23575/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@bd59477
07-03 20:16:04.823 23575-23575/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@836a8e4
07-03 20:16:04.824 23575-23575/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@b13914d
07-03 20:16:04.928 23575-23575/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
07-03 20:16:42.530 23575-23575/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = ru.pacodelavega.techno_test
07-03 20:16:42.530 23575-23575/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test V/Monotype:     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
07-03 20:16:42.543 23575-23575/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@a1cd5b0
07-03 20:16:42.543 23575-23575/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@d82cc29
07-03 20:16:42.546 23575-23575/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@b9b9bae
07-03 20:16:42.546 23575-23575/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@1447d4f
07-03 20:16:42.610 23575-23575/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-03 20:16:42.610 23575-23575/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
07-03 20:16:42.633 23575-23575/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-03 20:16:42.633 23575-23575/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-03 20:16:42.653 23575-23575/ru.pacodelavega.techno_test W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

Project code if it helps: https://github.com/pacodelavega/techno_test/

Comment: Is this coming from your own device? I do not see any signs of this class in the Android source code, so I do not know where it is coming from.

Comment: Yes, I justed tested on emulator and haven't got this error. Seems to be a virus or something.

Comment: I got the same issue with one device. Is it connected with missing library of something?

Comment: I reset my device to factory defaults and it disappeared. Guess it was some malware.